# DFS using 1D like 2D vector

Tags: c++, c++11

When the adjacency list is created in a 1D vector, how can it be used like a 2D vector in the for loop for dfs.

```
int dfs(int node) {
    int visCount = 1;
    visited[node] = true;
//this part!
    for (auto neighbour: graph[node]) {
        if (!visited[neighbour]) {
            visCount += dfs(neighbour);
        }
    }
    return visCount;
}
```

Comment: You are going to have to explain what you mean by "the adjacency list is created in a 1D vector".  in the code you posted above `graph[node]` returns probably a reference to some kind of container of neighbors, meaning `graph` is a vector or hashtable of a container type. Are you asking how you can make it work if `graph` is not a vector of adjacency lists? Well then you have to tell us what graph is. I mean are you just asking how to represent a 2D array as a 1D array?

Comment: Yes, how do I represent 2D array as a 1D array?

Comment: then do you want to represent graph as an adjacency matrix or still as adjacency "lists" but with each row of fixed size and padded out with 0s or something for nodes that have fewer neighbors than the number of columns? ... your question is under-specified.

Answer (score 0):

You can represent a 2D array as 1D array by choosing either a row-major or column-major ordering and just doing the math. e.g. this is for row major, where `cols` is the number columns in the 2D array:

```
int get_1D_index_from_row_col(int row, int col, int cols) {
    return col + row * cols;
}
```

Then to represent a graph using the 1D array you need to choose whether you want to use an adjacency matrix of booleans or adjacency "lists" of some maximum size. Below is an example of the adjacency lists version (because that is what the code you posted seems to use). The 2D array being represented as a 1D array has 5 rows and 4 columns. The row *n* is the adjacency list of node *n*. We allow for up to 4 neighbors and pad with -1's for nodes with fewer than 4 neighbors.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <functional>

int get_1D_index_from_row_col(int row, int col, int cols) {
    return col + row * cols;
}

void dfs(const std::vector<int>& graph, int num_nodes, int max_neighbors, std::unordered_set<int>& visited, int node, const std::function<void(int)>& visit) {
    if (visited.find(node) != visited.end()) {
        return;
    }
    visit(node);
    visited.insert(node);

    //recurse over neighbors...
    for (int i = 0; i < max_neighbors; ++i) {
        int neighbor = graph[get_1D_index_from_row_col(node, i, max_neighbors)];
        if (neighbor >= 0) {
            dfs(graph, num_nodes, max_neighbors, visited, neighbor, visit);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    std::unordered_set<int> visited;
    std::vector<int> graph = {
        1,  2, -1, -1,
        0,  2,  3, -1,
        0,  1,  3,  4,
        1,  2, -1, -1,
       -1, -1, -1, -1
    };

    dfs(graph, 5, 4, visited, 0,
        [](int node) {
            std::cout << "visited node " << node << "\n";
        }
    );

    return 0;
}
```